# Divisibility of a sequence of numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, divisibility

Suppose a sequence is defined by $u(1)=1$ and $u(n)= (n-1)u(n-1)+1$.

When does $n$ divide $u(n)$?

Numerical evidence shows that $1,2,4,5,10,13$ work. The only odd primes seem to be $5,13$ and $37$. The answer is probably all the divisors of $9620$, but I don't know how to prove this. $u(n)$ is $\displaystyle(n-1)!\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k!}$  in closed form, but that doesn't seem to achieve anything.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This is sequence [A064383](https://oeis.org/A064383).

Comment: Your sequence $u(n)$ is [OEIS sequence A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522) with a different offset.